# Menu name in hexagon shaped inline tag

Tags: html, css

```css
.hexagon span {
  color: #0f0f0f;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 0px;
}
.hexagon {
  font-size: 40px;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  line-height: 45px;
}
.hexagon,
.hexagon:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.hexagon.red,
.hexagon.red:after,
.hexagon.red:before {
  background: #ed8990;
}
.hexagon.aqua,
.hexagon.aqua:after,
.hexagon.aqua:before {
  background: #8dd7d8;
}
.hexagon.orange,
.hexagon.orange:after,
.hexagon.orange:before {
  background: #fd8a78;
}
.hexagon {
  width: 80px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 50px 25px;
  background: #48d1b2;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.hexagon:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -22px;
  left: 16px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #b5adac;
  transform: rotate(-54deg) skewY(23deg);
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: inset -1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.hexagon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -22px;
  left: 16px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #b5adac;
  transform: rotate(-54deg) skewY(23deg);
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <a class="hexagon red">
      <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
      <br/>
      <span>Some menu name</span>
    </a>
    <a class="hexagon aqua">
      <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
      <br/>
      <span>Foo</span>
    </a>
    <a class="hexagon orange">
      <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
      <br/>
      <span>Barbazzzzz </span>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have some hexagon shaped links. I try to add the name of the menu, but there are some problems.

There should be a bigger space between the hexagon's bottom and the name of the menu. `margin-top` wont help on the inline `span`.

If the name is too long, the spacing is too big between the lines. Even if I set it to `line-height: 0px`

http://jsbin.com/wohuyubiso/3/edit?css,output

Comment: How do you want the output too be?

Comment: optimally under the hexagon, about 10px, centered to the hexagon's width (80px)

Comment: @Paulie_D I added the code to my question as a snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem you just need to make the name `display: block`.

So, you need to add something like:

```
.hexagon span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/wojuhoravo/edit?html,css,output

Of course it would be nice to use `div` with proper class name instead of `span` in this case.

Comment: thank you for your quick solution. I works great but I have an issue with it: http://jsbin.com/himuyasavu/1/edit?html,css,output . If I add a div below #menu, its text appears under the menu name.

Comment: -^^ please review you answer.

Comment: It is not so easy with your DOM elements structure. I've changed it a bit. I think it is also  a bit more clearer now (for example menu item text shouldn't be inside of hexagon).

http://jsbin.com/pevexofuxe/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

just add this change that will be work for you

```css
.hexagon span{
     display: block;
    top: 25px;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```